# How to have a single pipeline run and single commit in github?

Tags: gitlab, github, github-actions

In jenkins, we can schedule poll scm to check for every 1 hr, 2hr,etc.

In the meanwhile, even if we add n number of commits, let’s say poll scm is 1 hr

After 1 hr, it will check for latest commits and if any new, it will launch once. If no commits, it won’t run the pipeline.

Is there any similar approach in github actions?

Our build process takes atleast 1 hr.

By the time it completes, if there are 2 commits added, it is keeping 2 pipeline runs in queue.

In gitlab merge requests, when I create an MR for my dev branch, it will merge all the new commits as a single commit including all those changes.

But, in github, when a pull request is created, it is merging all the commits (say 10) and creates a new commit as pull request merge, (10+1).

Any possibility to have similar approach like gitlab?

I saw squash option but it is not the same as I saw in gitlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a stash and merge option when you are merging the pull request.
That will combine all the commits as a single commit